# Assign unique ID for every new Class (not instance!)

Tags: java, architecture, game-engine

I was wondering, whether it would be possible to assign a unique ID for every new class (not instance!).

Example of what I mean:

```
public class ChildObjectOne extends SuperClass {}
public class ChildObjectTwo extends SuperClass {}

public SuperClass {
   private final int ID;

   public SuperClass() {
      this.ID = newID();
   }
}

final ChildObjectOne childObjectOne = new ChildObjectOne();
final ChildObjectTwo childObjectTwo = new ChildObjectTwo();

System.out.println(childObjectOne.getID()); //prints 1
System.out.println(childObjectOne.getID()); //prints 2

childObjectOne = new ChildObjectOne();
childObjectTwo = new ChildObjectTwo();

System.out.println(childObjectOne.getID()); //prints 3
System.out.println(childObjectOne.getID()); //prints 4
```

What I want it to do instead is print 1 and 2 again. It should generate a new ID for every new class, but if I create a new instance of that class, I want the ID to stay the same.

I tried to achieve this using generics:

```
public SuperClass<T> {
   private static int ID;

   public SuperClass() {
      this.ID = newID();
   }
}

public class ChildObjectOne extends SuperClass<ChildObjectOne> {}
public class ChildObjectTwo extends SuperClass<ChildObjectTwo> {}
```

I was hoping, it would count passing a different T as a new class, but that didn't work. Instead the ID is the last one that was set.

How can I achieve this kind of ID system?

Comment: You want a static ID for each class you create ? Not dynamically generated ? If you want the ID to be the same on every instance of the class, just create a Constant for each class with the ID value.

Comment: @Rabbit Yes, I have thought of that as well, but since I have a large number of these SubClasses, it would be very impractical to hardcode every ID. They should be dynamically generated for each class.

Comment: `this.getClass.getName()` or for static classes `MyClass.class.getName()`

Comment: exactly as @HomeIsWhereThePcIs mentioned. That is the qualified classname and should serve as a unique per-class ID that you don't have to generate or maintain yourself.

Aside from that, if you can elaborate more as to what you need to achieve with this ID system then perhaps there are better/different ways to realise that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand upon my comment, the class name will give you an unique String ID. If you want that ID to be a number you could do something like this:

```
class IdGenerator{
    private static int counter = 0;
    private static HashMap<String,Integer> classIdMap = new HashMap<>();

    public static synchronized int getId(Class clazz){
        if (classIdMap.containsKey(clazz.getName())) {
            return classIdMap.get(clazz.getName());
        } else {
            classIdMap.put(clazz.getName(), ++counter);
            return counter;
        }
    }
}
```

And then from your class you would do:

```
IdGenerator.getId(this.getClass());
```

The generated IDs **might not be the same** every time you run your app, depending on how it is structured.
For example:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
if (in.nextInt() < 100) {
    System.out.println("a = " + new Aclass().id); // a = 1
    System.out.println("b = " + new Bclass().id); // b = 2
} else {
    System.out.println("b = " + new Bclass().id); // b = 1
    System.out.println("a = " + new Aclass().id); // a = 2
}
```

Comment: I think you could make this `private static int counter = 0;` as an AtomicInteger to avoid any potential concurrency issues and probably a `ConcurrentHashMap` instead

Comment: Good note about multithreading, I have added the synchronized keyword to the method.

Answer (score 1):

## `Class::getName`

Each class in Java already carries a unique identifier: the [**fully-qualified name**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.7) of the class. No need for you to add an identifier.

Access the fully-qualified name by calling [`Class::getName`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html#getName()).

For a class:

```
String.class.getName()
```

> "java.lang.String"

For an object (an instance), call [`Object::getClass`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#getClass()), and then `Class::getName`.

```
customer.getClass().getName()
```

> com.example.invoicing.Customer